# Выбрать первую ячейку из нечетной строки jquery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Селектор для выбора первую ячейку из нечетной строки jquery и вставка в нее текста:

```
        $('[tr td:first-child]:odd').text('текст');
```

Мой вариант не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("tr:even td:first-child").text('текст');
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ln9w39g/1/)

Comment: odd -четные поменяй на even

Comment: @sepgg исправил